# Python: Writing to a File

Tags: python

I've been having trouble with this for a while. How do I open a file in python and continue writing to it but not overwriting what I had written before?

For instance:

The code below will write 'output is OK'.
Then the next few lines will overwrite it and it will just be 'DONE'

But I want both
'output is OK'
'DONE'
in the file

```
f = open('out.log', 'w+')
f.write('output is ')
# some work
s = 'OK.'
f.write(s)
f.write('\n')
f.flush()
f.close()
# some other work
f = open('out.log', 'w+')
f.write('done\n')
f.flush()
f.close()
```

I want to be able to freely open and write to it in intervals. Close it. Then repeat the process over and over.

Thanks for any help :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open the file in append mode. It will be created if it does not exist and it will be opened at its end for further writing if it does exist:

```
with open('out.log', 'a') as f:
    f.write('output is ')
    # some work
    s = 'OK.'
    f.write(s)
    f.write('\n')

# some other work
with open('out.log', 'a') as f:
    f.write('done\n')
```

Answer (score 3):

Just pass 'a' as argument when you open the file to append content in it. See the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

```
f = open('out.log', 'a')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to open the file in append mode the second time:

```
f = open('out.log', 'a')
```

because every time you open the file in the write mode, the contents of the file get wiped out.

Answer (score 2):

After the first writting, you need to use `f = open('out.log', 'a')` to **append** the text to the content of your file.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("appended text")
```